# How do I loop through a text file in Java adding a 7 line object to an array of objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, file-io

Im working on a project that is going to be a trivia game. I need to create a method that loops through a text file and creates an object then adds it to an ArrayList. Every 7 lines of the file is a new object. The object itself is a question containing things such as possible answers etc.

My Object Constructor:

```
 public Question(String question, int possibleAnswers, String[] answers, int correctAnswer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.possibleAnswers = possibleAnswers;
    this.answers = answers;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}
```

I need to loop through a file that has the question info like such:

```
Which of the following is not a programming language?
4
Python
Java
PHP
SQL
4
```

Im confused about how I should generate each object while looping through this is as far as I have gotten on the method:

```
public static ArrayList<Object> createQuestions(String filename) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<Question> questionObj = new ArrayList<Question>();
    Question questionArray[] = null;

    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            questionArray[i] = new Question(); 

        }
    }
    fileReader.close();
```

Comment: Why not store the objects as XML or JSON? Lots of library support for serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Its an assignment I'm working on so it has to be from a .txt file

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would break the problem down into methods like: `createQuestions`, `buildQuestion`, and `getPossibleAnswers`. That's basically what you'll be doing so just represent it with code. Like so (*left the fun parts out since you're a student and this is an assignment :)* ):

```
public static String[] getPossibleAnswers(Scanner scanner, int possibleAnswers) {
    // Get the possible answers by using the passed in int and scanner...
}

public static Question buildQuestion(Scanner scanner) {
    // Step through the first couple lines building your new question
    // and get q.question and q.possibleAnswers...
    // Now get the possible answers using the helper method
    q.answers = getPossibleAnswers(scanner, q.possibleAnswers);
    // Finish up
    return q;
}

public static ArrayList<Question> createQuestions(String filename) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    // Every time the reader has a next, it's another question
    while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
        // Here's a question
        questions.add(buildQuestion(fileReader));
    }
    fileReader.close();
    return questions;
}
```

Comment: Can you break down the buldQuestion method for me a little bit, thats the part I am struggling with the most.

Comment: You basically look at the file structure and handle each line. So, the first is the question, the second is the number of possible answers. Go ahead and get them however you need to. Then use the number of possible answers for getting them from the file and putting them in the array. The rest is more of the same from there @ChaceMcguyer.

Comment: So do I need to use a Scanner in that method as well? I wish things were as easy as Python.. To make sure I understand I parse through the document from index 0 --> index 6 (first 7 lines) and create a Question object in the buildQuestion method. Then I just call that method and add it to the questions array list?

Comment: Well, you're not really parsing through the document by index really; you could look at it like that but it might make it harder to understand; if I were to think of it that way, I would say that each index is an entire question. Anywho, yes, `buildQuestion` returns you a single question back. You can simply add that return value to the list directly.

Comment: What I wouldn't do is worry too much about how many lines a question is considering that perhaps some questions only have 2 answers (true/false) or n-answers. You probably want to let the question tell you how many possible answers there are and read the file accordingly. @ChaceMcguyer.

Comment: Thinking of it as index is whats messing me up. I am drawing a complete blank on how else I could pull the information from the file if I'm not using index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150551/discussion-between-chieftwopencils-and-chace-mcguyer).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to treat the file like it's indexed then here's a way. As you read the file, do so in chunks of 7 lines adding them to a string array. Sort of like you have.

```
while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
    String[] lines = new String[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7 && fileReader.hasNext(); i++) {
        // Fill the array with the lines that make up the current question
    }
    questions.add(new Question(lines);
}
```

Now, provide the constructor to match or have a builder that takes a string array and returns a question. (*I would opt for the builder*) Either way, there you'll move from the array to the actual values knowing that some are actually integers.

Answer (score -1):

A function for your refer. But a recommend that you should save your question list in an excel file for well formatted and easy to read also maintain.

```
public List<Question> createQuestion(String fileName){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("")));
        String line = null;
        int lineIndex  = 0;
        Question q = null;
        List<Question> listQ = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] answers = new String[4];
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){     
            if (lineIndex >= 7){
                lineIndex = 0;
                listQ.add(q);
            }
            switch (lineIndex){
            case 0:
                q = new Question();
                q.setQuestion = br.readLine();
                lineIndex ++;
                break;
            case 1:             
                q.setpossibleAnswers = br.readLine();
                lineIndex ++;
                break;
            case 2:
                answers[0] = br.readLine();
                lineIndex ++;
                break;
            case 3:
                answers[1] = br.readLine();
                lineIndex ++;
                break;
            case 4:
                answers[2] = br.readLine();
                lineIndex ++;
                break;
            case 5:
                answers[3] = br.readLine();
                q.setAnswer(answers);
                lineIndex ++;               
                break;
            case 6:
                q.correctAnswer = br.readLine();
                lineIndex ++;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }       
        }
    }
```

Comment: Won't every question have the same answers in the end?